# mac os web app not accessible on LAN

Tags: networking, ssh, mac, lan, web-application

I have a web app on port 3333 on my mac os (ventura). This mac has a static internal network IP (`192.168.1.234`). I want to access this web app from another machine on the. LAN via `192.168.1.234:3333`. When I hit that url from another machine, the address never resolves and gets stuck loading.

Strangely, I also have ssh access to that mac hosting the web app. The instant I ssh into that mac from the same machine that is trying to load `192.168.1.234:3333`, this address resolves and a get access to the web app.

### update

I don't even need to ssh **from that same machine** that is trying to access the web app. I can access the mac from another machine on the same LAN. It seems like this is "waking up" the mac to resolve the web app

So for some reason ssh into the machine also opens up the web app address in the brower

1. **why is that ?**
2. how can I access the web app without having to first ssh? The mac does not have a firewall enabled in place. So I am not sure what is blocking the access.